# emcee samples initial position

Tags: python, curve-fitting, emcee

I'm trying to fit a inverse gamma distribution to a histogram. I can easily pick out a set of good fit parameters by playing around with its two parameters (c.f. orange line in Fig1).

However, when I try to estimate the posteriors using emcee I simply sample the initial starting points of the chain.

```
import numpy as np 
import corner 
import emcee 
from scipy.special import gamma as gamma_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _inverse_gamma_distribution(x0, alpha, beta):
    return beta**alpha/gamma_function(alpha)* (1/x0)**(alpha + 1)* np.exp(-beta/x0)


flux =          np.array([0.,            0.,         0.08753462, 0.48757902, 0.59385076, 0.32146012, 0.20280991, 0.06542532, 0.01888836, 0.00369042, 0.00133481,  0.,            0.,         0.10504154, 0.44777665])
bin_center =    np.array([0.06898463,    0.12137053, 0.21353749, 0.37569469, 0.66099163, 1.16293883, 2.04605725, 3.59980263, 6.33343911, 11.1429583, 19.60475495, 0.06898463,    0.12137053, 0.21353749, 0.37569469])
error =         np.array([0.,            0.,         0.03914667, 0.06965415, 0.0579539,  0.03214601, 0.01924986, 0.00824282, 0.00333902, 0.0011127,  0.0005045,   0.,            0.,         0.04288303, 0.0667506 ])


def lnprior(theta):
    alpha, beta         = theta
    if 1.0 < alpha < 2.0 and 1.0 < beta < 2.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

def lnprob(theta, x, y, yerr):
    lp = lnprior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr)

def lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr):
    alpha, beta         = theta
    model               = np.array(_inverse_gamma_distribution(x, alpha, beta))
    return -0.5*np.sum((y - model)**2/yerr**2)

p0                      = [1.5, 1.5]

ndim, nwalkers          = 2, 100
pos                     = [np.array(p0) + 5e-1*np.random.randn(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]

sampler                 = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, lnprob, args=(bin_center, flux, error))
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 1000)
samples                 = sampler.chain[:, 500:, :].reshape((-1, ndim))

print("mean posterior: ", samples.T[0].mean(), samples.T[1].mean()) 
print("std posterior: ",  samples.T[0].std(),  samples.T[1].std())

fig                     = corner.corner(samples)

fig, ax                 = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale("log", nonposx='clip')
ax.set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
ax.set_ylim([0.0001, 10])
x                       = np.linspace(0.1, 20, 1000)

ax.errorbar(bin_center, flux, yerr=error, fmt=".")
ax.plot(x, _inverse_gamma_distribution(x, *p0))
for alpha, beta in samples[np.random.randint(len(samples), size=100)]:
    ax.plot(x, _inverse_gamma_distribution(x, alpha, beta), "-", color="grey", alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

The posterior mean and standard deviation correspond to the values I set in the `pos = [np.array(p0) + 5e-1*np.random.randn(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]` (i.e. [p0 +- 0.5]). Changing the number of steps and or the number of burned samples doesn't help.

[image: orange initial position]
[image: walkers stuck at position]

If I increase the number of walkers, it just samples the input position better - they never seem to go anywhere.

[image: More walkers]

There is this post [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176436/what-would-be-the-reason-that-the-posterior-distribution-looks-like-the-prior-us), but I don't think it applies here - the inverse gamma distribution is arguably a bit annoying but the curve fitting problem should be superbly defined..?

**-------------------EDIT--------------------**

I know understand the issue: removing the data points where the `flux` is zero causes the walkers to start moving and I get a result. I find this behavior a bit weird, so to update the question:
**why do two single outlier prevent emcee from moving?**

Answer (score 3):

The reason the walkers never started to move lies in the error array:

`error = np.array([0.,            0.,         0.03914667, 0.06965415, ... ])`

The first two values of `error` are `0.`. Thus the likelihood function `-0.5*np.sum((y - model)**2/yerr**2)`  is `-np.inf` for any value of `(alpha, beta)` and the walkers never start moving.
Removing these values or setting the errors to any nonzero value let's walker loose and the fit quickly converges as it should!